# set Image to Button

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, image, button

Could somebody help me a little bit with my issue below?

When I call the myFunction, images which I want to set to buttons appear after 2 sec simultaneously, not one by one with delay of 0.5 sec.

More info:

- generatedNumbers is array with four elements of NSNumber  (4,1,3,2)
- buttons are set in UIView via IB and are tagged (1,2,3,4)

---

```
-(IBAction) myFunction:(id) sender {
int i, value;
for (i = 0; i<[generatedNumbers count]; i++) {
    value = [[generatedNumbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i+1];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",value]];
    [button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [img release];
    usleep(500000);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What's probably happening is that this method is running on the main thread. Since it waits to finish when you call `usleep()`, the run loop never gets to the point where it's going to update the UI. Try creating an `NSTimer` and firing off a separate method every .5 seconds; that should give the main thread enough time to update.

Comment: Could you explain to me how to integrate NSTimer to my functionality?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html